# How can I shorten chained if/elsif statements?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to shorten the following method. Is there any clever way to do this in Ruby by using iterators, case statements or the like?

```
# Returns true iff this is a later date than the input date.
def later_than?(date)
    if(@year < date.year)
        return false
    elsif(@year > date.year)
        return true
    end
    if(@month < date.month)
        return false
    elsif(@month > date.month)
        return true
    end
    if(@day <= date.day)
        return false
    elsif(@day > date.day)
        return true
    end
end
```

I might add that the method belongs to a class named Date, along with three class members: year, month and day.

I know that the code can be shortened to some extent by excluding the particular if statements where false is returned, but I wonder if there is a better way? Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't that method be written as

    return @year > date.year || @month > date.month || @day > date.day

? And why do you use an elseif when just an if is required?
By the way, is that just an "example" to show what you want or THAT is the method where you required what you asked?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL:  Your simplification of the function would incorrectly tell us that Jan 2 2008 is later than Jan 1 2009.  The OP's function is correct, your simplification of it is not.

Comment: Ruby has a built-in `Date` class but it sounds like you are trying to write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I'll think about using the built-in class instead, then.

Comment: @David: You are right but the method he proposed has the same problem so I "emulated" it totally.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL:  Look more carefully, the first line of his function is `if(@year < date.year); return false` so his function would correctly tell us that Jan 2 2008 is NOT later than Jan 1 2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add this to your class:

```
include Comparable
def <=>(other)
  [@year, @month, @day] <=> [other.year, other.month, other.day]
end
```

your custom date class has suddenly gained these comparison methods: **<,   <=,   ==,   >,   >=**   and **between?** 
But as others have said, just use ruby's date class.

Answer (score 4):

Really, you should be using [`Date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html). You also don't need to compare attributes like `year`, `month` and `day` because `Date` implements `Comparable`. Here's what it looks like using whatever custom class you've created:

```
require 'date'

...

  def later_than?(date)
    Date.new(@year, @month, @day) > Date.new(date.year, date.month, date.day)
  end
```

But note the redundancy there. We're just building objects and comparing them. You probably want to just construct those `Date` objects or have some method that will return a `Date` object (which you would want if you do any more operations on dates), then use a simple `>` operator instead of creating a `later_than?` method. If you want to check it out in irb:

```
require 'date'
the_fourth = Date.new(2011, 7, 4)
christmas = Date.new(2011, 12, 25)
the_fourth > christmas # returns false
christmas > the_fourth # returns true
```

Also, if you really want that `later_than?` for semantic value, you could just do something like

```
require 'date'
class Date
  alias :later_than? :>
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would deserve a greater refactoring as there's no point in storing three different class variables when you could have only one time object and do the following :

```
def later_than?(date)
    @time >= date
end
```

Without having one global time variable, you could do :

```
def later_than?(date)
    Time.new(@year, @month, @day) >= date
end
```

Comment: Just be careful not to compare the time of day if that isn't required.

Comment: You should use the `Date` class instead of the `Time` class and use `>` instead of `>=`, but otherwise this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This will work too:

```
def later_than?(date)
   @year*10000+@month*100+@day > date.year*10000+date.month*100+date.day
end
```

What I like even more is this version:

```
def to_s
  (@year*10000+@month*100+@day).to_s
end

def later_than?(date)
  to_s > date.to_s
end
```

Comment: How about adding some white-space between operators for readability?

Comment: The former version is preferable, because it's unlikely that you would ever use that to_s method in any other context, and it involves unnecessary conversion to String and unnecessary object instantiation.

Your later_than? method could use <=> instead of >, and be renamed to <=> itself, thus supporting the Comparable module. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other recommendations of using Ruby's Date object. It's perfectly suited for what you want and will save you a lot of code reinventing that particular wheel.

As a recommendation on the use of `if/elsif` logic:

```
if(@year < date.year)
    return false
elsif(@year > date.year)
    return true
end
if(@month < date.month)
    return false
elsif(@month > date.month)
    return true
end
if(@day <= date.day)
    return false
elsif(@day > date.day)
    return true
end
```

is unnecessarily complicated. Consider this:

```
return false if ( @year  < date.year  )
return true  if ( @year  > date.year  )

return false if ( @month < date.month )
return true  if ( @month > date.month )

return true  if ( @day   > date.day   )
return false
```

I'm not saying this is appropriate for every situation, or that this is what you should use in this particular case. Rather, what I want to show is how the formatting can make it easier to see what is changing in repeating, similar, lines of text.

As you write your code look at how you lay it out and keep it clear and concise. Write it as if you were giving instructions to someone over the phone; Does your code flow like you'd say it in normal speech?

Write your code with maintenance in mind because if you have to go back to it later you'll want it to be easily understood.

Comment: Vim's "align" and "surround" plugins make it really easy to do that. Normally I don't like that many returns, but, yes, it seemed to make more sense because it kept it short and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the other approaches, but rather than using if and elsif, you could use `case`:

```
# Returns true iff this is a later date than the input date.
def later_than?(date)
  case
    when @year < date.year then false
    when @year > date.year then true
    when @month < date.month then false
    when @month > date.month then true
    when @day <= date.day then false
    when @day > date.day then true
    else raise "Shouldn't get here"
  end
end
```